# how to process cookie and session on HTTP Server

Tags: c, http, session-cookies, httpcookie

I am developing a http server by C/C++ (don't use other programing language) but i have a problem about process session and cookies ? .I dont understand this request .Who do help me now ? thank you !

Comment: squid cache server has a cgi server side, you can read the its code.

Comment: I found the following links for your: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm , its explain how to set cookie.

Comment: but my teacher request dont use open source library and only use SOCKET into C or C++ .I think CGI is open library ?? help me

Comment: i only programing on Windown . my request doesnt Linux

Comment: i think ms has same library, but if it doesn't has, you can use cygwin project or mingw project.